# Html Form on Submit button

Tags: html, forms, curl, post, url-rewriting

I need help. I have a basic html form which is below. Now when i call it up on my browser, i have two fields 
also know as:

Summary = summ
Description = comment

Now on the Submit button the action is to call a url, but i want the above two fields to be part of the url

So if i manually put John is Summary field & Smith in Description field, the url must catch the field values and be like

http://itds041/trackit/app%20-%20cop...EST+USER&summ=John&comment=Smith

> Blockquote

```
<form action="/trackit/app%20-%20copy/curl_create.php?thisuser=TEST+USER&summ=&comment=" method="post" target="_self">
```

Summary: 
Description:

> Blockquote

See screenshot to explain.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkRBz.jpg)

Regards
Shabeersa

Comment: If `POST` is used to submit form, it is NOT a good practice to include the posted Data in the URL. Is there any special reasons to do so? Maybe this is an x-y problem? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: No special reason, Basically i want on submit it must open url with the field parameters

Answer (score 0):

***"Now on the Submit button the action is to call a url, but i want the above two fields to be part of the url"***

There are 2 ways to make the value of fields as part of the URL:

1. **Use GET method in form.** This is the recommended way as it is easier and semantically more correct -- data in POST request normally is passed as body, not as part of URL.

   A simple jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/mtzqpprx/1/) is made for reference. After the form is submitted by clicking the *Submit* button, a `GET` request is sent, with fields data embeded in URL.
2. **Use POST method to submit the form**, but the HTTP request is sent by JavaScript, not by form's action.

   Another jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/jboq9qrw/1/) is made for example. The key steps here are:

   - `<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">`. Attach event listener for submit event.
   - `event.preventDefault();`. Prevent form element's default submission behaviour.
   - `var url = 'https://example.org/api?' + $.param(params);`. Construct URL with fields' data, and then send HTTP request to it. In the jsfiddle example, I choose to send Ajax request and print the response data.